# Browsers can't open .php file in xampp

Tags: html, web, browser, connection, compatibility

I was stuck here for a couple of hours. I tried opening my .php in htdocs (localhost/users) using Internet Explorer but it redirect me to download my.php file instead of opening it. I've also tried using Chrome and Opera but it shows cannot locate the file (localhost/users ).I've other related questions here but it seems none is fitting to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't open a PHP file directly. Navigate to the URL your web server is running on, usually http://localhost, but the port could differ depending on your configuration. If you set the web server (Apache) to run on a port other than 80, use a URL like http://localhost:1234 instead, where 1234 is the port number.

Comment: Thank you ooa. If I have users.php in htdocs and port 8080. What should I typed in on the url?  I tried above mentioned but it routed me to apache dsshboard. Again Thank you for your help. Newbie here

Comment: You would then use http://localhost:8080/users.php.